# Need to filter the systeminfo findstr

Tags: javascript, html, shell, electron

I'm trying to present the user and computer information in a Electron desktop app and so far it looks good. Howerver I need to refine it by filter out the `systeminfo | findstr` 'key' and only present the 'value'.
If I run this line: `let winOSName = shell.exec('systeminfo | findstr /C:"OS Name"')` in my .js-file I get: **OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro** with plenty of spaces in between the key and the value. Is there a way to filter out the 'OS Name:' here?

My .js-code:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
let path = require('path')

shell.config.execPath = path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'nodejs', 'node.exe')

function getData () {
// For Windows
  let winComputerName = shell.exec('hostname')
  let winUserName = shell.exec('whoami')
  // let winOS = shell.exec('ver')
  let winOSVersion = shell.exec('systeminfo | findstr /C:"OS Name"')
  let winOSOwner = shell.exec('systeminfo | findstr /C:"Registered Owner"')

  let computerNameTextField = document.querySelector('#computerName')
  let userNameTextField = document.querySelector('#userName')
  let osNameTextField = document.querySelector('#osName')
  let userEmailTextField = document.querySelector('#userEmail')

  computerNameTextField.setAttribute('value', winComputerName)
  userNameTextField.setAttribute('value', winUserName)
  osNameTextField.setAttribute('value', winOSVersion)
  userEmailTextField.setAttribute('value', winOSOwner)
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="formHolder">
  <form>
    Computer Name:
    <input type="text" name="computerName" id="computerName"><br>
    User:
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName"><br>
    OS:
    <input type="text" name="osName" id="osName"><br>
    User Email:
    <input type="text" name="osName" id="userEmail"><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by using a .substring(x, x). I hope it will work on other machines as well.
`let winOSOwner = shell.exec('systeminfo | findstr /C:"Registered Owner"')`
`let userEmailTextField = document.querySelector('#userEmail')`
`userEmailTextField.setAttribute('value', winOSOwner.substring(27, 48))`

Comment: It would be better to use [os module](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) of node.js to get the system info. Your approach would fail in linux/osx